# How to debug a C# "plugin" that is part of the same project?

Tags: c#, plugins

I'm writing a C# application that accepts plugins. The way I accomplished this is as follows:

- In my solution, create a project that contains a single interface that defines the expected methods of a plugin class.
- In the main application, add a reference to this project containing one interface.
- Add a third project to the solution which represents a plugin. This plugin also has a reference to the interface project.

In my main application, I scan a plugins folder for files matching a given filename (plugin_.dll). If such files are found, I load the assembly and then use reflection to look for any class that implements the interface. For any such class, I add an instance of it to a `List<IPlugin>`. The app then has access to all the plugins via this list.

This works great and I have successfully written a couple of very simple plugins.

Here's where I'm struggling:

- When I want to test the plugin, I have to first build the solution and then manually copy the built plugin into the correct location which the app scans. I know I can probably automate this by adding a post-build command though.
- More importantly, is there a good way to actually *debug* the code in the plugin? (single-step, exception breaks, etc.) Right now I simply run the app and see what happens. I use extensive `Console.WriteLine`s if I need to trace something. It's far less productive though than using VS's debugger.
- Less important at this particular point but could be a thing down the road: how would someone *else* debug the plugin? More specifically: if I start a new VS solution and make a reference to the interface assembly, is there any reasonable way to debug the code in my new plugin?

Comment: so, what you are looking for is called 'Dependency Injection' and one of the simplest/easiest tools available is native to .NET. It is called 'MEF' and comes in two versions. (MEF and MEF 2). Most of the work you did is directly translatable to MEF (Interfaces are usually used here, too). On top of that, the symbols/debug info are loaded automatically. The only thing left is that you need to keep copying the files.